# how implement delta time in C#

Tags: c#, console

I'm trying to implement the deltaTIme in c # to make an ascii style game. How can I do? this is what I did, but the result is always zero

```
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
 while (true)
            {
                float deltaTime = (currentDate.Ticks /1000f);
                deltaTime = (deltaTime > 0.05f) ? 0.05f : deltaTime;
                last = currentDate.Ticks;
                Console.WriteLine(deltaTime);

            }
```

Comment: Please add some print statement, so we can see your examples (you changed from Seconds to Ticks).

Answer (score 1):

There appear to be several issues with your code:

- You define `DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now` outside of your loop and never update it inside, so you never actually get the current time to see how much has passed.
- You define and assign a variable `last`, but you never actually subtract it from the current time. So no "delta" is being calculated.

Aside from that, you will still want to use the `Stopwatch` class as pointed out by Stephen McDowell instead of `DateTime.now`. This will in most cases use a much higher resolution for the underlying time measurement, which prevents rounding errors that could actually lead to always getting 0 once you calculate the delta properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8) class designed for this.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will output an increasing number that indicates how much time has passed since the start of the program. The point of "deltatime" in game development is to know how much time passed between two updates of the game. For example, at a constant framerate of 60 fps, you would have an average deltatime value of 0.016666 (= 1/60).